# How to respect view size inside RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have `RecyclerView` item with one image and two text views.

If the text is too long, it is causing that one item will be bigger then other item, and overall a bad UI.

What can I do to limit the text to respect the width of another view - the image in that case?(The "three dots" will be proper solution for me)

my layout code for recycler view item:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cast_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cast_name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cast_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cast_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cast_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cast_char_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cast_name_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cast_name_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cast_name_text" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Image for clarifying the problem -

[image: id]

Answer (score 0):

Well You are forcing each item to take require width by using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in each View. If you can fix the width of your ImageView then by using `android:maxWidth="XXdp"` in Text view you can achieve what you want.

Code will be as follows -

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cast_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"                 //here fixing width to 100dp
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cast_name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"                      //fixing TextView to max 100dp
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cast_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cast_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cast_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cast_char_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cast_name_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cast_name_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cast_name_text" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Following xml will result as -

[image]

Happy Coding !